# How to install V8Js for PHP on XAMPP for Windows?

Tags: php, windows, xampp, v8

Been working for days now trying to find an easy way to install V8Js on XAMPP for windows, yet with no success.

I have downloaded the latest XAMPP version with PHP version 7.2.0 VC15, and followed the instructions in this blog post - https://blog.xenokore.com/how-to-install-v8js-for-php-on-windows/ - but to no avail. I don't see a mention to V8Js in the phpinfo, and when I try to use it I get an ERROR

```
Error: Class 'V8Js' not found in...
```

I have downloaded the dll files from here - https://blog.xenokore.com/how-to-install-v8js-for-php-on-windows/ - and used the latest 7.2.1 VC15 x86 ts version with no success.

Can anyone offer some help?

Comment: same problem here, if you try using any `php` command this error occurred `PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'v8js' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\v8js (The specified module could not be found`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to download lasted php version from here instead https://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?t=6359

Then move a `php_v8js.dll` from `php\ext` into same directory on your local.

But with 5 files additional from root directory of php have to move into your `apache\bin` instead

- icui18n.dll
- icuuc.dll
- v8.dll
- v8_libbase.dll
- v8_libplatform.dll

Be sure to have it in your `php.ini`, by adding the following line:

```
extension=php_v8js.dll
```

Then try to restart apache or check by command `php -m`, have fun.

Comment: Note, that following the link above there are 2 types of x64 builds: `non thread safe` and `thread safe`. 

This `https://phpdev.toolsforresearch.com/php-7.2.3-nts-Win32-VC15-x64.zip ` is non-thread safe as marked by `nts` suffix. Another one `https://phpdev.toolsforresearch.com/php-7.2.3-Win32-VC15-x64.zip` is thread-safe. I used files mentioned in the answer above from thread-safe build on my Win 8.0 x64 and it worked.

Comment: Do not forget to add a variable to your php.ini, pointing to icudtl.dat (which you need as well). Something like
v8js.icudtl_dat_path=[path]/icudtl.dat

Comment: i tried this but receiving this error. when doin php command on powershell.PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'v8js' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\v8js (The specified module could not be found

Comment: I follow the apachelounge website mentioned above and ended up on this page [v8js release](https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/v8js/) but cannot find the dll file. Is there any other way to get the dll file?

Comment: @arhakim you need to download from `My builds` from the forum link. The first post always updated so you don't need to navigate to other page.

Comment: I just downloaded `https://phpdev.toolsforresearch.com/php-8.2.0-Win32-vs16-x64.zip` but can't find `php_v8js.dll` or any other file with `v8` in it.