# How to install php-v8js on window

Tags: laravel, vue.js, server-side-rendering

Now, i using vuejs and laravel. when i see view page source (Ctrl+U) but have not html code.I went to find in google.And found need to use Server side rendering
(I learned form https://medium.com/js-dojo/server-side-rendering-with-laravel-vue-js-2-5-6afedd64aa90) But problem is "Class 'V8Js' not found"

Someone can help ?

sorry  I don't speak English that well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that V8JS is a PHP library, that is not shipped by default and you have to compile it by yourself. You can learn more about it and how to install it on it's [GitHub page](https://github.com/phpv8/v8js). Follow the installation instructions for your local machine operating system and you should be good to go. If you would like to deploy your app to your hosting provider, first you have to make sure that your host has this PHP extension compiled and enabled. Hopefully this helps you :)

Comment: i installed but not work (references https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48203147/how-to-install-v8js-for-php-on-xampp-for-windows)

Comment: Have you edited your php.ini conf to enable the extension?

Comment: now problem is PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_v8js.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application.can you told me. what's this problem ?

Comment: Could you share your php.ini via pastebin or a similar service? Also make sure the file 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_v8js.dll' exists.

Comment: I can installed v8js.But when i run this error is show (V8Js::compileString():9272: ReferenceError: window is not defined)

Comment: Okay great you resolved the php v8 issue, the only problem now is that you need to create a separate javascript for client and server. The error  you are gettting is because on the server javascript doesn't have the global window object. Thus, you have to make two separate files for server and client javascript. What framework do you use?

Comment: I’m using vuejs framework.i learned from topic https://medium.com/js-dojo/server-side-rendering-with-laravel-vue-js-2-5-6afedd64aa90

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173701/discussion-between-j-arbet-and-best-best).