# Install v8js on windows laravel/yii2

Tags: vue.js, v8js

I installed v8js by [click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48203147/how-to-install-v8js-for-php-on-xampp-for-windows) but it does not work, the project on laravel does not see v8js, please tell me how to properly connect it to the project

Comment: Instead of asking this as new question try posting/commenting on the existing post

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install V8Js for PHP on XAMPP for Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48203147/how-to-install-v8js-for-php-on-xampp-for-windows)

Comment: No, this question didn't solve my problem